# opengl 2d image grid in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need to draw a gridded image using opengl. I've read that images created using grids allows to do various effects on images, like the famous wave effect, or a ripple effect from this link:

http://www.soulstorm-creations.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=111:opengl-making-a-2d-grid-image&catid=18:programming-articles&Itemid=39

I've also gone through lesson 6 android port from NEHE Tutorials:
http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/

I can convert it from cube to rectangle, but I need help in understanding 
1) why we are using vertex coordinates in terms of 0 and 1? Why have they not used coordinates according to image width and height?
2) How can we divide the texture region in small grids as explained in tutorial above? If some one can guide on 1), I guess I can work on point 2).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertex coordinates are from 0 to 1 so that you can use vertex data with many different textures without worrying about the dimensions of the image.
That said, for pixel perfect operations you often have to often the texture coordinates by a fraction the image's pixel width (say 0.5f * (float) image->width()) and height in order to make sure OpenGl (or d3D) samples from the correct place.

As for dividing the grid, straight forward simple linear interpolation. If you have a grid going from pixel coordinates 0 to 100 and you want 10 steps in your grid, you start at 0 and increment in steps of 10 pixels :

```
  vertex_xi =  (start_x + ((end_x - start_x) / 10) * i));
  vertex_yi =  (start_y + ((end_y - start_y) / 10) * i));
```

similarly,, for texture coordinates, you'd do the same thing only you usually name them like this:

```
  vertex_ui =  (start_u + ((end_u - start_u) / 10) * i));
  vertex_vi =  (start_v + ((end_v - start_v) / 10) * i));
```

where 'start_u' and 'start_v' are '1.0f  +/- offset and  end 'end_u' and 'end_v' are '1.0f +/- offset'. Put those in your vertex array and you should be good to go.

HTH.

Comment: I'm confused. In my case, what will be end_x? If you go through lesson 6 android port from NEHE Tutorials: http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/, you will see an indices array. What will be my indices array when I increase the number of vertices?

Comment: start_x and end_x are screen pixel coordinates. Your indices refer to the list of vertices. You have a list of vertices and putt those in a buffer. When you actually come to draw the triangles, you must tell OpenGL which vertices you are refering to. This is often done with index buffers.

Comment: if you are drawing a quad you will need 4 vertices (actualy physical location of positions and their uv coordinates) and a total of 6 indices for two triangles. Each index is a single 16 or 32bit value that refers to an actual vertex.

Comment: Thanks Luther, I got it working. I can render a gridded image. Any clue as to how I can scale the image and not keep it to a 1x1 square? I might also need to translate the origin to the bottom of my screen.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, that's easily done. Using the Above code just adjust the position of start_x/start_y and end_x/end_y. Setting start_x to 0, end_x to 100 and start_y to 0 and end_y to 100 will give you a grid 100 units in size, centered on 50,50.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to apply various effects on the image grid using Opengl in android. But the performance is too slow. Any tips for optimizing it?

Comment: If you can show me the code, I might be able to help more. Using fixed point format is usually a win on phones, although some will be ok with floating point (no idea how to determine which one is best right now!)